# synchronized statements java -- what exactly do they do vis-a-vis non synchronized code?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

Do synchronized statements in java protect against modification of the object synchronized on in other threads which are accessing the thread WITHOUT synchronized statements?  I am new to multithreaded programming and am confused by the documentation I've found on this issue.

Let's say I have the following code.

```
public class Test {
public ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Test(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
    this.items = items; 
}

public void perform() {
    synchronized(items) {
        int size = items.size();
        for(int n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
              for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
                  items.set(i, items.get(i) + 1);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

While the inner loop in "perform" is running, is it possible for "items" to be modified in another thread despite the fact that the whole loop is contained in a "synchronized(items)" statement?  Or does the "synchronized" statement only protect against modification by other blocks which use "synchronized(items)" themselves to request the lock on "items"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In addition to Rob answer and addressing literal meaning of question's title: `synchronized` block of Java code introduces _synchronization order_ relationship between threads executing `synchronized` code block. Look up JLS to see how/if it helps your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronizing on an object does not mean no other thread can modify it. It means that other threads which *also* synchronize on that object must wait for your lock to be released.

> Or does the "synchronized" statement only protect against modification by other blocks which use "synchronized(items)" themselves to request the lock on "items"?"

Thus, this statement is correct.

Comment: Synchronization does not only _just_ lock it also provides a memory barrier to local thread changes to central storage and to update local storage from central @vancan1ty.

Comment: @Gray Could you provide a link which discusses what you just mentioned?  (The memory barrier).

Comment: @Gray raises a good point -- synchronization also imposes a 'happens-before' relationship.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070184/hashmap-stuck-on-get/17070215#17070215

Comment: Here's another great link on the subject: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html

Answer (score 3):

Threads executing code that modifies your items outside of a synchronized block are free to modify the items, even if another thread is executing the synchronized code. You have to be careful to synchronize everywhere (no help from the compiler or runtime system). This is one aspect that makes writing multi-threaded code difficult.

Answer (score 0):

synchronized statements says it executes some "non-thread-safe" codes(or "critical area"), and blocks other threads that try to run synchronized statements(that means, non-thread-safe codes) until it completes.

but other thread that executes no critical area, will not be blocked.

And synchronized statements uses "mutex". mutex says an object, which one the critical area modifies. (which one in the synchronized declaration)

In case of yours, it is

```
items
```

.

other threads that uses different mutex, (not uses the "items") will not be blocked also.

below might help you: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html