# BPEL, threads stucked on HashMap.getEntry?

Tags: xml-parsing, garbage-collection, soa, bpel

I am new to SOA, and currently we met a problem when using BPEL to do some XML transformation.
we have 3 SOA projects will do something like:

1. Read input files from folder which is in text format
2. Save file content in Database and put on AQ
3. Read file id from AQ, load content from database, and transform to our internal XML format
4. apply some business logic and transform content back to text format.

SOA proejct1 do step 1-2, project2 do step 3 and project3 to step4.

We are doing some load test with input 7000 files.

the problem we experienced is that the memory use of "Old Generation" keep accumulating, although major GC can reduce it, it still keep growing, until 100%. Then no new BEPL instance can be created, and we met transaction timeout.

after analyze heap dump, we get a result like below, it seems that BPELFactoryImpl hold a HashMap which more than 180M, and it will keep growing. so does anyone experienced something similar?

we use SOA version 12.1.3. this problem stopped us for weeks, please help, thanks a lot.
[Image of heap analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6L1x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Guys

Finally we got an answer on this, it was caused by a bug, as said by Oracle Support, we are waiting for the patch.
thanks for your attention.

It's a bug. You should raise an SR referring for: stuck threads on

```
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:465)
 at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:417)
 at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLNode.setUserData(XMLNode.java:2137)
 at oracle.bpel.lang.v20.model.impl.ExtensibleElementImpl.doCreateElement(ExtensibleElementImpl.java:502)
 at oracle.dp.entity.impl.EmFacadeObjectImpl.getElement(EmFacadeObjectImpl.java:35)
 at oracle.bpel.lang.v20.model.impl.ExtensibleElementImpl.performDOMChange(ExtensibleElementImpl.java:707)
 at oracle.bpel.lang.v20.model.impl.ExtensibleElementImpl.doOnChange(ExtensibleElementImpl.java:636)
 at oracle.bpel.lang.v20.model.impl.ExtensibleElementImpl$DOMUpdater.notifyChanged(ExtensibleElementImpl.java:535)
 at oracle.dp.notify.impl.NotifierImpl.emNotify(NotifierImpl.java:39)
 at oracle.dp.entity.impl.EmHolderImpl.doNotifyOnSet(EmHolderImpl.java:53)
 at oracle.dp.entity.impl.EmHolderImpl.set(EmHolderImpl.java:47)
 at oracle.bpel.lang.v20.model.impl.CopyImpl.setTo(CopyImpl.java:115)
 at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.v2.wmp.BPEL2xCallWMP$CallArgument$1.evaluate(BPEL2xCallWMP.java:190)
 at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.v2.wmp.BPEL2xCallWMP.invokeMethod(BPEL2xCallWMP.java:103)
 at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.v2.wmp.BPEL2xCallWMP.__executeStatements(BPEL2xCallWMP.java:62)
 at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.common.wmp.BaseBPELActivityWMP.perform(BaseBPELActivityWMP.java:188)
 at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.performActivity(CubeEngine.java:2880)
 ....
```

Bug 20857627 (20867804) : Performance issue due to large number of threads stuck in HashMap.get

Comment: I think they should use concurrentHashMap here, instead of HashMap, which is not thread safe.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070184/hashmap-stuck-on-get